There are some people in neighborhood wanting to put in community pool. There are some that do not want it. Can those not interested be forced to pay?
I purchased my home in a brand new community with the builder as the HOA and there was no plan for a pool to ever be built.
After I moved in I put in a request to the HOA to have a pool installed in my back yard, and it was approved and I had one put in.
Now, 3 years later, and the builder is almost done and the HOA is going to be turned over to the homeowners. There are some people talking about putting in a community pool, and I am not interested for obvious reasons.
My question is, can I be forced to participate financially in the pool in any way?

No
You are free to sell your property and no longer be a part of the HOA.
While you are part of it, it’s participatory democracy - you can advocate for your point of view (no pool), but if you lose the vote, you lose the vote.
This is what you agreed to by buying into a HOA.

Your bold No is misleading. The key part of the answer is in the last two paragraphs. If there is a majority of owners in favor than all owners are bound by the result. So yes, OP is very much forced to participate financially. Some sources with relevant laws that explain what HOAs can or cannot enforce with simple majority decisions would also be useful.

Also, as far as I understand, a new pool may require a supermajority of the HOA members (e.g. 66% or 75%) - that will depend on the applicable laws and the HOA's bylaws. But the basic point still stands.

@sleske Do you have a source for such laws? That would make a much better answer.

@quarague no, the Op can always sell up and leave - there’s no compulsion to stay. That’s what the “no” refers to.

@DaleM I'm aware that this is technically true in that sense. In analogy, there are frequently questions of the form 'can I sue about X?' Writing, yes you can sue and than afterwards explaining that the case has zero chance of success is also technically true. But it is not a useful answer to the question.

Is this really a clear question of law as opposed to the specific bylaws of the HOA? I don't know the first thing about these "HOA" things, but won't there be some sort of contract involved laying out the terms of what is and is not within the purview of the HOA?

@quarague: Unfortunately, I do not know any specific laws - just my general impression from some googling. Maybe someone with more specific knowledge can chip in.

@terdon It would be a matter both of the HOA's bylaws and also state law regulating HOAs.
